# How to print tab in printer

Tags: java, printing

I have to print receipts through a thermal printer using Java.
And for the format, I can understand how to print align center base on the manual like below:

**center manual:**

```
[Name] Select justification 
[Format] ASCII   ESC a n 
         Hex     1B 61 n 
         Decimal 27 97 n 
[Range] 0 ≤ n ≤ 2, 48 ≤ n ≤ 50 
[Description] Aligns all the data in one line to the specified position. 

 n selects the type of justification as follows: 
   n    Justification 
 0, 48 Left justification 
 1, 49 Centering 
 2, 50 Right justification
```

so the code below works:
**center code:**

```
    private void printAlignCenter(){
        byte[] cmd = new byte[3];
        cmd[0] = 0x1B;
        cmd[1] = 0x61;
        cmd[2] = 0x01;
        wfComm.sndByte(cmd);
    }
```

now, the tab setup and tab manual:
**tab manual:**

```
[Name] Set horizontal tab positions 
[Format] ASCII   ESC D n1...nk NUL 
         Hex     1B 44 n1...nk 00 
         Decimal 27 68 n1...nk 0 

[Range] 1 ≤ n ≤ 255 
        0 ≤ k ≤ 32 

[Description] Sets horizontal tab positions. 
        ▪ n specifies the column number (counted from the beginning of the 
          line) for setting a horizontal tab position. 
        ▪ k indicates the total number of horizontal tab positions to be set. 

[Name] Horizontal tab 
[Format] ASCII HT 
         Hex 09 
         Decimal 10 
[Description] Moves the print position to the next horizontal tab position
[Notes] ▪ This command is ignored unless the next horizontal tab position 
          has been set.
```

but the code below not works:
**tab code:**

```
    private void printTabEnable(){
        byte[] cmd = new byte[3];
        cmd[0] = 0x1B;
        cmd[1] = 0x44;
        cmd[2] = 0x28;
    //     cmd[3] = 0x08;//08//10
    //     cmd[4] = 0x12;//12//20
            wfComm.sndByte(cmd);
    }

    private void printTab(){
        byte[] cmd = new byte[1];
        cmd[0] = 0x09;
        wfComm.sndByte(cmd);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are missing the `NUL` byte to end the tab setting:

```
private void printTabEnable(){
    byte[] cmd = new byte[4];
    cmd[0] = 0x1B;
    cmd[1] = 0x44;
    cmd[2] = 0x28;
    cmd[3] = 0x00; // Terminates the tab setup
    wfComm.sndByte(cmd);
}
```